# Alignment problem when I write a lot of map

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, alignment

When I write a lot of map the alignment of map is not good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,xcolor,enumitem}

\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pzccal }
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
        cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{blue}}{}{}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\function}[5][]{     % Function
    \ifx &#1&
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\
        \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5
    \end{array}
    \else
    \begin{array}{ccrcl}
        \displaystyle #1 & : & \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\[10.5pt]
        &   & \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5
    \end{array}
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\functions}[7][]{    % Functions
    \ifx &#1&
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\
        \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5 \\
        \displaystyle #6 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #7
    \end{array}
    \else
    \begin{array}{ccrcl}
        \displaystyle #1 & : & \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\
        &   & \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5 \\
        &   & \displaystyle #6 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #7
    \end{array}
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!35!black]
    alors les applications:
    
\[
\function[f]{\widetilde{\mathscr{X}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{A}}}{X}{A=\mathcal{O}_{X}(X)}
\]
    
\[
\function[f^{-1}]{\widetilde{\mathscr{A}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{X}}}{A}{X=Zar(K\mid A)}
\]
    
\[
\function[g]{\widetilde{\mathscr{A}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{W}}}{A}{W=\{R\in Zar(K\mid A)\mid R\text{ est un point fermé de } Zar(K\mid A)\}}
\]
    
\[
\function[g^{-1}]{\widetilde{\mathscr{W}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{A}}}{W}{\mathcal{O}_{W}(W)}\]
    
\[
\function[h]{\widetilde{\mathscr{W}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{X}}}{W }{X=\{R\in Zar(K)\mid \overline{(R)}\cap W=\emptyset\}}
\]
    
\[
\function[h^{-1}]{\widetilde{\mathscr{X}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{W}}}{X}{W=\{\text{L'ensemble des points fermé de } X\}}
\]
    
sont des bijections,chaque application est l'inverse d'autre application en ligne.
    
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

it looks like that:

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE community! What you mean with ˙*map*? Equations? I would write them using `align*` math environment defined in the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Zarko, the TO means the mathematical term of a function, i.e. mapping A to B.

Comment: Welcome. // Where do you want the alignment? for the mapping-arrows? For the functions names (to the left)? For the colon (:)? Please specify, e.g. as a handmade sketch or screenshot, added to your question. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO, it may be, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Zarko, I'm sure ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO i use new-command function for typeset this new-command don't work with align.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I'm not familiar to all jargons used in math. After all, I'm not a mathematician  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you after for something like this (so far this is not clear from your question):

[image]

- I estimate that using your functions is (almost) impossible to obtain above result.
- With direct writing of code for your math terms in `tcolorbox` its content is -- according to my opinion -- more clear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pzccal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,
            mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\zar}{Zar}
\everymath{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{blue}}{}{}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!35!black]
alors les applications:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
f:      &\quad &    \widetilde{\mathscr{X}}
                    &   \to     \widetilde{\mathscr{A}}     \\
        &       &   X
                    & \mapsto   A = \mathcal{O}_{X}(X)      \\[1ex]
f^{-1}: &       &    \widetilde{\mathscr{X}}
                &   \to \widetilde{\mathscr{A}}             \\
        &       &   A
                    & \mapsto   X = \zar(K\mid A)           \\[1ex]
g:      &       &   \widetilde{\mathscr{A}}                
                    &   \to     \widetilde{\mathscr{W}}     \\
        &       &   A   
                    &   \mapsto W=\{R\in \zar(K\mid A)
                                    \mid R\text{ est un point fermé de } 
                                    \zar(K\mid A)\}         \\[1ex]
g^{-1}: &       &    \widetilde{\mathscr{W}}
                    &   \to \widetilde{\mathscr{A}}         \\
        &       &   A   
                    &   \mapsto \mathcal{O}_{W}(W)          \\[1ex]
h:      &       &   \widetilde{\mathscr{W}}
                    &   \to     \widetilde{\mathscr{X}}     \\
        &       &   W   
                    &   \mapsto X=\{R\in \zar(K)\mid \overline{(R)}
                                    \cap W=\emptyset\}      \\[1ex]
h^{-1}: &       &    \widetilde{\mathscr{X}}
                    &   \to \widetilde{\mathscr{W}}         \\
        &       &   X
                    &   W = \{\text{L'ensemble des points fermé de } X\}
\end{alignat*}

sont des bijections,chaque application est l'inverse d'autre application en ligne.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it just that the alignment in my latex look ugly and i want a better solution.

Comment: another question if possible,i prefer if for example in the definition of the set W in the map g,that the set take two or three line better than be long like that and thanks.

Comment: @Kaneki1013, yes, it is possible. For such cases `mathtools` package provide environment `multilined`. However, you can also use other elements as `aligned`, `split` etc. For more help I suggest you to ask new question, if you will not be able to implement mentioned environments.

Comment: @Kaneki1013 (continuation of afore comment): Inserting mentioned environments may require to a bit reorganize `alignat˙ environments (move ampersand after `to` and `mapsto` symbols).