# How to make small set

Tags: math-mode, braces

i have a map such that image of an element is a set

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,xcolor,enumitem,mathrsfs,pzccal,mdframed}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\apptocmd{\[}{\color{blue}}{}{}
\newcommand{\function}[5][]{     % Function
    \ifx &#1&
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\
        \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5
    \end{array}
    \else
    \begin{array}{ccrcl}
        \displaystyle #1 & : & \displaystyle #2 & \longrightarrow & \displaystyle #3 \\[10.5pt]
        &   & \displaystyle #4 & \longmapsto     & \displaystyle #5
    \end{array}
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\[\function[g]{\widetilde{\mathscr{A}}}{\widetilde{\mathscr{W}}}{A}{W=\{R\in Zar(K\mid A)\mid R\text{ est un point fermé de } Zar(K\mid A)\}}\]
\end{document}
```

the image look like that

[image: 1]

but i wish it to be something like that

[image: 2]

what your advice and thanks

Comment: with respect to the long list of packages you use, I suggest to review their manuals again: there will be a few which provide a solution you request. find them on ctan.org . // It's also a good idea to follow links to the right under Related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not entirely clear to me, what you after. Provided code is not even close to showed image, so I assume, that this your question is actually follow-up question to your [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693950/alignment-problem-when-i-write-a-lot-of-map) one.

In this case, you can write your math expression with use of `multlined` math environment as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pzccal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,
            mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\zar}{Zar}
\everymath{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
g:      &\quad  &   \widetilde{\mathscr{A}} \to  {}            
                    &   \widetilde{\mathscr{W}}     \\
        &       &   A \mapsto  {}
                    &   W=\{R\in \zar(K\mid A)\mid R:\\
        &       &   &               \begin{multlined}[t] 
                                    \text{est un point fermé de} \zar(K\mid A)\}         
                                    \end{multlined}\\[1ex]
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

- However, if you like to reproduce showed image, than you need to write your math from scratch.
- Please advice, what you actually after (showed curly bracket are a bit confusing).

**Addendum:**
A MWE, which reproduce in question showed image, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,
            mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{Bmatrix}
\text{some text}                                            \\
\mathcal{O}_{X} - \text{ modules $\mathcal{E}$ of rank $n$} \\
\text{such that $\mathcal{E}\mid U_i \cong \mathcal{O}_{U_i}^n$ for all $i$}
    \end{Bmatrix}
    \longmapsto \check{H}^1 (\mathcal{U}GL_n(\mathcal{O}_X))  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to use `\textup` instead of `\text`.

Comment: @SandyG, of course I may :-), So far my primary intention was to clarify what OP is after. After then I can /would replace `\text` with `\textup` in the cases, that solution would be used in `theorem`  or similar environments . This (should) not be a big deal :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot.it seem i don't explain my question,i don't want my set to be to long,instead of one long line,i want three short line and B matrix work well for me.

Comment: @Kaneki1013, than you try now explain what you after. Do any of my examples is close to what you like to have? BTW, you have sufficient reputation that you can upvote answer, so instead saying "thank you" you should upvote it ;-).

Comment: Done,yes your example using B matrix.